# Connect to data/service wsdl URL introspect error

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, sharepoint, flex4, flash-builder

Hi I am trying to add a web service in flex 4. This web service is deployed in share point 2010 in the intranet . I am able to see this wsdl file through browser but trying to introspect the service is giving an authentication error.
I am getting the following error :-

There was an error during service introspection.
WSDLException: faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: Unable to resolve imported document at 'http://sql2008:47672/_vti_bin/StoryboardingDatabaseConnect.asmx?WSDL'.: java.io.IOException: Authentication failure

Edit :-
Have added the video showing the error at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=moXfxmiHAqQ

Comment: What do you mean when you say you are trying to "Add a web service in Flex 4."  Are you trying to consume the Web Service with the WebService class?  Or something else?

Comment: I am using connect to Data/Service wizard in Flash Builder 4, I have a webservice running on the sharepoint server which I want to consume in my flex application. While introspecting the wsdl of the service, the connect to data/service wizard is giving me the following error.

Comment: I think it's an 'Authentication failure' as the error says....

Comment: but do you know how to correct this , I can open the same asdl file in browser but it doesn't give any error.I have not added any cross domain file , since I don't have any clue about what it is . Is that causing trouble ?

Comment: You should provide some detail (source code) about how you connect to the service, how you authenticate, so we to have something to actually correct. Without them nobody can point to a problem, just guess what it could be.

Comment: Have added the video on youtube showing the error , please see the edit in the original post

Comment: And where do you authenticate? You might try editing the generated code to insert an authentication section before accessing the service.

Comment: @rekaszeru : I am actually clueless about web services, touched it for the first time 3 days before.Do you know about a tutorial telling about the authentication in web service and flex. In my application I am able to use the web service normally without using this wizard , I am wondering what is going on wrong running this data/service wizard.

Comment: please see my post, you can find useful links there beside the solution for authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Data Services Wizard does not support (as of now, afaik) connection to https services, neither to ones that need authentication.

So you should add your credentials manually to your soap request's header using name-value pairs:

```
[{name: "userName", value: "yourUserName"}, 
{name: "password", value: "yourPassword"}].
```

You can read more about it in the [Working with SOAP Headers](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_3.html) section of this article (Using WebService components).

You might also find [this post from the Adobe forums](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/448254) useful, elaborating this issue.